# Move + Submit Input when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a command line interface simulator with html/css/js(jQuery which I am very new to), and I am trying to move the text before the input AND the input box to the next line whenever you press enter (just like a console when you run a command). I have done research but I am not at all sure of how one would go about doing this. Any tips on doing this or just about my code in general? Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
   //alert("ENTER!");
      //Submit input and move everything to the next line
  }
 });
});
```

```css
html {
 background-color: #000000;
 font-family: Menlo;
}

.console {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.green {
 color: #39ff14;
}

input {
 background: transparent;
 border: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Menlo;
 font-size: 15px;
}

p {
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="console">
  <span class="green">usr_501$ </span>
  <input type="input" name="input" id="input" autocomplete="off"><br>
 </div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $('#submitted').append('<span class="green">usr_501$ </span>' + $('#input').val() + '<br>');
      $('#input').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: Menlo;
}

.console {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.green {
  color: #39ff14;
}

input {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Menlo;
  font-size: 15px;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="console">
  <div id="submitted"></div>
  <span class="green">usr_501$ </span>
  <input type="input" name="input" id="input" autocomplete="off"><br>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I just updated it, because I noticed that prepending would result in a reverse order compared to a normal console.
So now its appended to an extra area for the submitted content.